# C root inode numbers different using dirent

Tags: c, stat, inode, dirent.h

I have written a C program that is meant to display the path of the file from the root given to it by the user. However, I am having a problem comparing Inode numbers using opendir/readdir and the corresponding direntp. Mainly, when I use these to write a (struct) stat, the inode number is vastly different to what I get without using them.

I have put comments next to each line saying what each one does, and included the output of the program at the bottom of this post. Any help to fix this problem would be very much appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int found = 0;    //declaring stuff
struct stat D; 
struct stat ES; 
struct dirent* direntD; 
struct dirent* direntE; 
DIR* dirp;
char currDir[1024];
char newDir[1024];

stat(argv[1], &D);    //load the starting directory into a stat struct 
printf("loaded %s into D\n", argv[1]);    //prints out the directory that has been inputted
printf("Inode number is %ld\n", (long) D.st_ino);    //prints out the inode number

strcpy(newDir, currDir);    //make the path to the parent directory
strcat(newDir, "/..");

printf("%s\n", currDir);    //print out the starting and parent directories
printf("%s\n", newDir);

dirp = opendir(newDir);    //open the parent
while ((direntE = readdir(dirp)) != NULL){    //read the files in the parent
    printf("%s\n", direntE->d_name);    //print names of files in the parent
        stat(direntE->d_name, &ES);    //load file into stat struct ES
        if(ES.st_dev == D.st_dev){    //compare device numbers
            printf("st_dev are the same\n");    //if true, print this
            if(ES.st_ino == D.st_ino){    //compare inode numbers
                printf("st_ino are the same\n");    //if true, print this
                printf("The child Dir is %s\n", direntE->d_name);    //also print the file/directory in the parent that links to the child
                found = 1;    //variable that says i've found what i want
            } else {
                found = 0;
            }
        } else {
            found = 0;
        }
        printf("%ld\n", (long) ES.st_ino);    //printing these to check they both match
        printf("%ld\n", (long) D.st_ino);

        }
    closedir(dirp);    //close dir
}
```

Output from terminal

```
./pathto /usr (pathto is the name of my program, starting in root/usr)
loaded /usr into D 
Inode number is 131073 
/usr
/usr/..
home
0
131073
root
0
131073
..
st_dev are the same
3408247
131073
usr
st_dev are the same
3408247
131073
.
st_dev are the same
3679535
131073
```

Comment: nop's answer is right. You're calling `stat` on the entries from `dirent`, but these names are just are just single path components, which by themselves serve as **relative paths**. `stat("foo", &buf)` means "look in the *current working directory* for `foo` and deposit information about it in `buf`"

Comment: Look at how the numbers **do not change** sometimes between loop iterations, e.g. 3480247 and 3480247.  Why is that? Because `stat` is failing and you didn't check. It's failing because the name doesn't exist in whatever current directory you are running the program from.

Comment: Lastly, why don't you retrieve the `d_ino` field from the `struct dirent`? There is no need to `stat` a directory entry just to find out the inode number. A Unix directory (by classic definition!) maps names to inodes.